# Kafka-HDFS-Connector- Sending Data From Kafka to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, confluent-platform

In machine **A** kafka is running  and in machine **B** hadoop is installed.
Now I want to write data to hadoop from kafka.
I have installed Confluent Platform in Machine **A**.

Can anyone guide what configuration i have to add to write data from kafka to hadoop which is running on different machine

Comment: [Edit] your question to include what you've tried and the errors you get, if any

Answer (score 5):

You can find the full documentation for the Kafka Connect HDFS [connector here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html).

There's a tutorial in the [quickstart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart). To try it out, modify `etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties` as required and then load it using

```
confluent load hdfs-sink -d etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties
```

Comment: Hi @Robin I am trying by this tutorial only.

Comment: I have edit this file also etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties where i put hdfs://ipaddress:port but i dont know i have to do some changes in hadoop machines also or not

Comment: Hi! How do i load my modified properties if i using ambari (HDP)? Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ambari, sorry.